# Cannot install ruby-vips, 'no pkg_config libvips'

Tags: ruby, vips

I am running Elementary OS and I just installed libvips-dev using apt-get.  When I run "gem install ruby-vips -v '0.3.9'" I get this error:

```
extconf.rb:27:in `<main>': no pkg_config for any of following libvips
 versions: 7.29, 7.28, 7.27, 7.26, 7.24, 7.23, 7.22, 7.20 (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

From my simple knowledge, maybe this means that the gem cannot find the installation of libvips-dev (I know it is required.)  What does this error mean and how do I install this library?

Comment: https://github.com/jcupitt/ruby-vips/issues/63 looks similar and suggests PKG_CONFIG_PATH may need to be set manually.

Answer (score 0):

`ruby-vips` uses `pkg-config` to find `libvips`. Try running this at the command-line:

```
$ pkg-config vips --cflags
-D_REENTRANT -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 ....
```

If you get an error, `pkg-config` is not finding vips correctly. You need to check that you have a `vips.pc` file and that it's on your `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.